# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes

Tags: java, spring, maven, ssm

guys.I am new here.

I try to run a simple `JUnit` test case for `spring` service class and `dao` class, but it fails and I get this exception. It is a `maven` project and I use the `tomcat v7.0`.

I will show the Failure trace in following .It has no console.

Please Help。

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(java/lang/reflect/Annotateenter Element;java/lang/String;)
org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;
        at org.springframework.test.util.Menter code hereetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:349)
        at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:191)
        at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:208)
        at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:166)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:271)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.<init>(DefaultTestContext.java:67)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:103)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:115)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
```

The following is my maven project's **pom.xml**.

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- junit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 4)Spring test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 1. -->
        <!-- slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 2.mysql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DAO: MyBatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3.Servlet web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- json -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    <!-- 4.Spring -->
    <!-- 1)Spring core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring.version}</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 2)Spring DAO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 3)Spring web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- redis:Jedis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>protostuff-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>protostuff-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Looking forward to your quick answer.Thanks!

Comment: For starters stop mixing spring versions and tomcat 7 is hardly a Servlet 3.1 container ( you will need 8 or up for that).

Comment: Which spring and other dependencies version should I use in  pom.xml?   should I use the v8 tomcat?

Comment: The current problem you have is that your `spring-test` dependency is a different version then you r other Spring dependencies. Next if you deploy the app it will blow up because Spring 5 requires a Servlet 3.1 container (whereas Tomcat 7 is a 3.0 container).